# Change value of mysql field before return result

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, sql-update

I normally handle this in the code , just wanted to check if could be done directly in the query

e.g scenario

```
TABLE : PRODUCTS
ProductID  |OnPromotion   |PromotionEndDate
1           Y              31-12-2014
2           Y              20-10-2014
3           Y              31-12-2014
```

In the above scenario if wanted to get a list of all items **BUT**
for items where PromotionEndDate is less than curdate() it should change the OnPromotion field to 'N'
And then serve the result. IS this possible in mysql ?

Comment: You can run `UPDATE` then `SELECT`. It's fine to do something in 2 queries.

Comment: Yes, MySQL has `IF ... ELSE` clause

Comment: If you mean "update a value in a select clause", then the answer is no. You'll need a stored procedure, or one update and one select to do that.

Comment: Do you actually want to change the value stored in the table, or just return a different value in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    ProductID,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN PromotionEndDate < CURRENT_DATE()
            THEN 'N'
            ELSE OnPromotion
        END
    )AS OnPromotion,
    PromotionEndDate
FROM
    PRODUCTS
```

Comment: Wow that works , very clever ! will select in 3 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First update the data in table then select desired data

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS SET OnPromotion = 'N' WHERE PromotionEndDate < CURRENT_DATE();
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS
```